# How to handle sessions on multiple account servers / while scaling horizontally?

Tags: node.js, express, session, load-balancing

I'm working on a web app and want to do it properly, so I'm keeping scalability at the back of my mind. One thing that is boggling my mind is how to handle sessions on multiple servers.

**Short Example:**
Let's say **Anna** logs in on my web page and the load-balancer redirects her to **server X**. **Server X** stores **Anna**'s session data and shortly after **Anna** closes the web page.
After 10 minutes or so, **Anna** opens the page again and gets redirected to **server Y**. Her session should still be alive.

How does *server Y* know it's her?

```
  │
  ├── Anna ─> load-balancer ─> Server X ─> Session Data on X
  │
10 mins pass
  │
  └── Anna ─> load-balancer ─> Server Y ─> How to get session data on X?
```

---

- Is there a possibilty to serve authenticated api requests sessionless?
- Is it best practice to store session data on a central data base?
- Is there another common solution I might not know how to search for?

I'm very greatful for any answers but especially if in context of node/express apps. 
In general I am looking for best practice solution, as I'm eager to learn.

Comment: You can use sticky sessions (load balancer always send you to the same server where the session object is kept) or you can use centrally stored sessions (some sort of shared database) that any server can access.

Comment: You can serve authenticated API requests sessionless.  It just means you have to include a credential with each API request that you can verify in a sessionless way (looking something up in a database from any server).

Comment: Your Anna session question is a little confusing because you say Anna logs off.  That would usually clear any login credential and any temporary session data so when Anna comes back, she will have to reauthenticate.  That is the purpose of a log off.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're completely right. My explanation was confusing. I fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out! :) Also thanks for the recommendation on a shared database. That one seemed weird to me in a decentralized environment but I guess it's still common as you can do redis clusters and stuff.

Comment: We could use sticky Sessions. Then the request will go to the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this scenario, there is some options you can check:

1. If you need to store access tokens (oauth), you can use redis, a fast database to check the token by any Node.js server in each request (https://redis.io)
2. You can use JWT, in that case, the token is secure thanks to the calculated sign (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)
3. Use sticky sessions, in that case each user request will go to same server. NOT recommended

For step 1 and 2, you can send the token in the http Authorization header

Comment: Thank you very much pointing out these options! Both option 1 and 2 look very promising. I'm gonna mark this answer as accepted.